# Free Xenserver License Renew

Tags: xenserver, licensing

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Can you help me with my software licensing question?](https://serverfault.com/questions/215405/can-you-help-me-with-my-software-licensing-question)

I have a question

Do you know if the Free Xenserver License could be renewed? This license last a year and I want to know what I must do when it expires, if I can get a new free license and how or if I should purchase another kind of license.

Thank for your answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'll have to request a new license at the end of one year (and yes, you can get a new free license). We're using it here at work and just went through it about a month ago.

XenCenter will warn you starting at 1 month out from expiration. Don't forget to renew, or your VMs will not boot (but they will continue to run).

Answer (score 1):

As with all licensing questions, you're better off asking the ones that provided you with the license in the first place.

Answer (score 0):

just get another free license

Here is a related post

[Citrix XenServer 5.5 Licensing](https://serverfault.com/questions/36196/citrix-xenserver-5-5-licensing)